# Select all individuals who have certain properties on a given date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use dynamic properties to manage the characteristics of individuals. I have a table IndividusDynPropValues with 1 line for each individual and each property For example:

```
ID  StartDate   ValueString ValueFloat  ValueDate   Individus_ID    IndividusDynProp
14  2018-09-10  Outside     NULL        NULL        3               Out Status
13  2018-08-15  Dead        NULL        NULL        1               Out Status
12  2018-08-02  Male        NULL        NULL        3               Sex
11  2018-07-28  #DBNULL#    NULL        NULL        1               Out Status
10  2018-07-25  Sold        NULL        NULL        1               Out Status
9   2018-06-07  Unk         NULL        NULL        3               Sex
8   2018-06-07  Adult       NULL        NULL        3               Status
7   2018-06-06  Femal       NULL        NULL        2               Sex
6   2018-06-06  Adult       NULL        NULL        2               Status
5   2018-06-03  Male        NULL        NULL        1               Sex
4   2018-06-03  Adult       NULL        NULL        1               Status
3   2018-05-23  Egg         NULL        NULL        3               Status
2   2018-05-23  Egg         NULL        NULL        2               Status
1   2018-05-21  Egg         NULL        NULL        1               Status
```

'#DBNULL#' means that the individual is on site again. I want to create a function that takes a date for the input parameter and returns a table with the ID of each individual who belong to the groups “Male living on site” at the date. An individual is part of the group if Sex = 'Male' AND (Out Status IS NULL OR Out Status = '#DBNULL#')
So in the example, if the date enter in the function is “2018-07-20” it returns:

```
Individus_ID
1
```

if the date is “2018-08-10” it returns:

```
 Individus_ID
 3
 1
```

if the date is “2018-08-17” it returns:

```
Individus_ID
3
```

I’ve tried that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Groupe_Individus_Male_Vivant (@daDate datetime)
RETURNS @TGrMalesVivants TABLE (
        TList_Individual [varchar] (50) NOT NULL 
    )

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @TtempGrMalesVivants TABLE (TList_Individual [varchar] (50) NOT NULL)    
DECLARE @TtempGrMales TABLE (TList_MIndividual int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @TtempGrMales 
    SELECT DISTINCT Individus_ID
    FROM IndividusDynPropValues

DECLARE @selectedOutStatus VARCHAR(50),
        @sBirdId int,
        @tmpSex VARCHAR(3)

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TtempGrMales)
                BEGIN

                    SELECT TOP 1 @sBirdId = TList_MIndividual FROM @TtempGrMales 

                    SELECT @selectedOutStatus =IDPV.ValueString
                                        FROM [dbo].[IndividusDynPropValues] AS IDPV
                                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                    FROM [dbo].[IndividusDynPropValues] AS IDPV2
                                                    WHERE IDPV.Individus_ID=IDPV2.Individus_ID
                                                    AND IDPV.IndividusDynProp_ID=IDPV2.IndividusDynProp_ID
                                                    AND IDPV2.StartDate>IDPV.StartDate AND CONVERT(smalldatetime,IDPV2.StartDate,120 )<=@daDate)
                                        AND CONVERT(smalldatetime,IDPV.StartDate,120 )<=@daDate
                                        AND IDPV.Individus_ID =@sBirdId
                                        AND IDPV.IndividusDynProp_ID='Out Status'


                    SELECT @tmpSex= IDPV.ValueString
                    FROM [dbo].[IndividusDynPropValues] AS IDPV
                    INNER JOIN TSaisie AS TS ON TS.TSai_PK_ID=IDPV.Saisie_ID
                    INNER JOIN TProtocole AS TP ON TP.TPro_PK_ID=TS.TSai_FK_TPro_ID
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM [dbo].[IndividusDynPropValues] AS IDPV2
                                WHERE IDPV.Individus_ID=IDPV2.Individus_ID
                                AND IDPV.IndividusDynProp_ID=IDPV2.IndividusDynProp_ID
                                AND IDPV2.StartDate>IDPV.StartDate AND CONVERT(smalldatetime,IDPV2.StartDate,120 )<=@daDate)
                    AND CONVERT(smalldatetime,IDPV.StartDate,120 )<=@daDate
                    AND IDPV.Individus_ID =@sBirdId
                    AND IDPV.IndividusDynProp_ID='Sex'
                    AND TPro_Importance = (SELECT Max(TP2.Tpro_Importance) 
                                              FROM IndividusDynPropValues IDPV3
                                              INNER JOIN TSaisie AS TS2 ON TS2.TSai_PK_ID=IDPV3.Saisie_ID
                                              INNER JOIN TProtocole AS TP2 ON TP2.TPro_PK_ID=TS2.TSai_FK_TPro_ID
                                                WHERE IDPV3.Individus_ID=@sBirdId
                                                AND IDPV3.IndividusDynProp_ID=4
                                                AND IDPV3.StartDate>=IDPV.StartDate
                                                AND CONVERT(smalldatetime,IDPV3.StartDate,120 )<=@daDate)

                    IF @tmpSex='Male' AND (@selectedOutStatus IS NULL OR @selectedOutStatus='#DBNULL#')
                        BEGIN 

                            INSERT INTO @TtempGrMalesVivants (TList_Individual) 
                            VALUES (@sBirdId)

                        END

                    DELETE TOP (1) FROM @TtempGrMales
                END

 INSERT @TGrMalesVivants
    SELECT * 
    FROM @TtempGrMalesVivants
    RETURN 

 END
```

it works but it takes 1:55 with all the table (1859732 lines) so it’s too long

Comment: That takes too long because you have a multi-statement table valued function. This is almost always even slower than a scalar function. But then you slow it down even more by using a loop. You also have some very serious logical problems in your code. You are selecting and deleting top 1 but none of those queries have an order by. As such, you may not always get the same row. This needs to be rewritten as a set based solution instead of row by agonizing row.

Comment: What is the goal of the function you have here? there's quite a lot to take in for it, so if we can understand what it does, we might be able to better help you convert the function from a multi-line table-value function to an inline table-value function.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for this comment, I onky been using sql for 2 months so I don't really understand what you mean by "This needs to be rewritten as a set based solution instead of row by agonizing row." I've change the code with an order by, like you've suggested !

Comment: @Larnu the goal of the function is a little complex to explain. I'm doing some tests to find the best way to select individuals who will be part of a group in order to more easily verify which individuals are in each group

Comment: What I mean is you need to write this as a single query, not a loop. Loops are horribly inefficient in the database world. We need to understand what you are trying to do. Not a vague explanation of the business case, an actual detailed explanation of the data movement. You might want to take a peek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some inspiration/direction on how to ask these types of questions.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't know how to whrite this as a single query, that why I've used a loop... What don't you understand about what I'm trying to do? (I'm so sorry, I thought my question was clear, especially since I tried to follow the advice you sent)

Comment: Well to help I would need to be able to run queries. You have posted a rows of sample data for one table (I think it might be IndividusDynPropValues). You have at least two more tables listed in your function. The biggest challenge you are facing is that you are using an EAV style of database. This adds layers of anguish which most of the time can be avoided with a better design. I would probably use ROW_NUMBER to be able to get all properties for a given date. But I have no idea how this is all related to the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. Notice how I posted sample data? This is a good example for what you should do in the future.

Some conditional aggregation should work here. You need this aggregation because your data is denormalized into an EAV and you need to reassemble this into a normalized table. This works for the sample data and your desired output. You can uncomment the set @MyDate line to see the second value working.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#IndividusDynPropValues') is not null
    drop table #IndividusDynPropValues

create table #IndividusDynPropValues
(
    ID int
    , StartDate date
    , ValueString varchar(50)
    , ValueFloat float
    , ValueDate date
    , Individus_ID int
    , IndividusDynProp varchar(50)
)

insert #IndividusDynPropValues values
(14, '2018-09-10', 'Outside', NULL, NULL, 3, 'Out Status')
, (13, '2018-08-15', 'Dead', NULL, NULL, 1, 'Out Status')
, (12, '2018-08-02', 'Male', NULL, NULL, 3, 'Sex')
, (11, '2018-07-28', '#DBNULL#', NULL, NULL, 1, 'Out Status')
, (10, '2018-07-25', 'Sold', NULL, NULL, 1, 'Out Status')
, (9 , '2018-06-07', 'Unk' , NULL, NULL, 3, 'Sex')
, (8 , '2018-06-07', 'Adult' , NULL, NULL, 3, 'Status')
, (7 , '2018-06-06', 'Femal' , NULL, NULL, 2, 'Sex')
, (6 , '2018-06-06', 'Adult' , NULL, NULL, 2, 'Status')
, (5 , '2018-06-03', 'Male' , NULL, NULL, 1, 'Sex')
, (4 , '2018-06-03', 'Adult' , NULL, NULL, 1, 'Status')
, (3 , '2018-05-23', 'Egg' , NULL, NULL, 3, 'Status')
, (2 , '2018-05-23', 'Egg' , NULL, NULL, 2, 'Status')
, (1 , '2018-05-21', 'Egg' , NULL, NULL, 1, 'Status')

declare @MyDate date = '20180720' --returns Individus_ID 1
--set @MyDate = '20180810' --returns Individus_ID 1, 3
;

with MySortedData as
(
    select i.*
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by i.Individus_ID, i.IndividusDynProp order by i.StartDate desc)
    from #IndividusDynPropValues i
    where i.StartDate <= @MyDate
)

select s.Individus_ID
    , OutStatus = max(case when IndividusDynProp = 'Out Status' then ValueString end)
    , Status = max(case when IndividusDynProp = 'Status' then ValueString end)
    , Sex = max(case when IndividusDynProp = 'Sex' then ValueString end)
from MySortedData s
where s.RowNum = 1      
group by s.Individus_ID
having isnull(max(case when IndividusDynProp = 'Out Status' then ValueString end), '#DBNULL#') = '#DBNULL#'
    and max(case when IndividusDynProp = 'Sex' then ValueString end) = 'Male'
```